# On Types and quantifier free formulas

Tags: model-theory

Hey could somebody have a look at the following proof atempt and tell me if im on the right way ? Thanks in advance!

Claim: Let $M$ and $N$ be two structures and $a \in M$ and $b \in N$. TFAE.

1.) (a,b) is a partial isomorphism between $M$ and $N$.

2.) $tp(a) \cap  QF =  tp(b) \cap  QF$

where QF is the set of quantifier free formulas.

$(1 \Rightarrow 2)$

Since we have a local ismorphism between $M$ and $N$ we know that $M$ and $N$ satisfy the same formulas, so by definition $ tp(a)=tp(q) $. Now since  both models satisfy the same set of quantifier free formulas, we get immediately the desiderata.

Comment: Did you mean **partial** isomorphism?

Comment: Yes! I meant partial ismorphism

Comment: Your argument is wrong : the partial isomorphism will only tell you that $\langle a \rangle_M \cong \langle b \rangle_N$.

Comment: @Oliver Roche : Agree! But cant I still conclude that $Tp(a)= Tp(b)$ from $\langle a \rangle_M=  \langle a \rangle_M$ ?

Comment: No, we can't conclude that the types are equal, but the quantifier free types are equal, which is what you want..

Comment: We certainly *don’t* know that $M$ and $N$ satisfy the same formulas (sentences?) and it wouldn’t follow from that that $a$ and $b$ have the same type, nor does it actually follow from the assumption that $a$ and $b$ have the same type (that would follow from partial elementary). What it does mean is that $a$ and $b$ satisfy the same atomic formulas, which can be readily extended to quantifier free formulas.

Comment: Thanks @spaceisdarkgreen . Just to be precise, in order to show that this extends to all QF formulas. I guess I have to do an induction on the complexity of $\varphi$ (which is trivial since I aready have my I.H). Am I right ?

Comment: Thanks @Olivier Roche!!

Comment: @Eddie show the definition of partial iso implies they satisfy same atomics and then this is the base case for an easy induction. The atomics part is probably more work, depending on definitions and what detail you need to show it in. It’s the same as the proof that an embedding  preserves atomic formulas.